# edit button to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, alter

I got my database to work, and I can add my data and get return on it again. That is perfect, because it is the first time that I get it to work, and it opend up a lot of possibilies. So my next project here, is to ALTER my table in MySQL with a button. Until now it looks like this:

[image]

I can add a date, day, fromtime and totime. But I would like to have the possibility to change fx the day, if I make a mistake when I add the values to my database. I started on making an edit button in the right hand side. So overtime I make a new row, there will come a new edit button. But does anybody know how I can asign my button to the ALTER TABLE query? Or maybe a hint how to do it?

Best Regards to all
From Mads

EDITED CODE:

I have made the primary key in the database p_id. I also get a return from the p_id

```
  <html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/arrangeTables.css">

</head>

<body>

    <form method="post">
        <h3>Add your worktime to database</h3><br>
            <input type="date" name="date"><br><br>
            <select name="day">
                <option value="Mandag">Mandag</option>
                <option value="Tirsdag">Tirsdag</option>
                <option value="Onsdag">Onsdag</option>
                <option value="Torsdag">Torsdag</option>
                <option value="Fredag">Fredag</option>
                <option value="Lørdag">Lørdag</option>
                <option value="Søndag">Søndag</option>
            </select>
            <input type="time" name="fromtime">
            <input type="time" name="totime">
            <input type="submit" value="submit"><br><br>

    </form>


</body>

<?php
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$hostname = "127.0.0.1:3306"; 

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
 or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
echo "Connected to MySQL<br><br>";

//select a database to work with
$selected = mysql_select_db("danskebank",$dbhandle) 
  or die("Could not select any database");

// Insert to database
$date = $_POST['date'];
$day = $_POST['day'];
$fromtime = $_POST['fromtime'];
$totime = $_POST['totime'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO addWorkTime(date, day, fromtime, totime) VALUES('$date', '$day', '$fromtime', 'totime')";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

//Return records from database
$result = mysql_query("SELECT date, day, fromtime, totime FROM addWorkTime");
?>



    <!-- Return from the database -->
    <h3>Return from database:</h3><br>

  <!-- headers -->
        <tr>
            <th class="column1">Date</th>
            <th class="column2">Day</th>
            <th class="column3">From</th>
            <th class="column4">To</th>
        </tr>

        <!-- Now a row for each new set of data, here you probably need to
        loop through some data set you retrieve from the database -->
        <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)): ?>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td class="resultcolumn4"><?php echo $row{'p_id'};?></td>
            <td class="resultcolumn1"><?php echo $row{'date'};?><br></td>
            <td class="resultcolumn2"><?php echo $row{'day'};?></td>
            <td class="resultcolumn3"><?php echo $row{'fromtime'};?></td>
            <td class="resultcolumn4"><?php echo $row{'totime'};?></td>
            <td><a href='link_to_the_add_or_edit?id='.<?php $row['id'] ?></td>

            <?php

            $id=$_GET['id'];

            echo '<input type="hidden" name="name_of_hidden_input" value='.$id.'>';
            //and the rest of the form

                if($_GET['submit']){

                    //Some mysql injection prevention first
                    update danskebank SET date=['?'] where id= $_GET['name_of_hidden_input']
                }
            ?>
          </tr>
          <?php endwhile; ?>
    </table>
</html>
```

Comment: Alter table query? What do you mean? You mean how to update the right row of the table?

Comment: Hey Loko. Thanks for the answer. Maybe bad formulated of me. Yes that is what i mean. So when you press edit, then you can edit the specifik row.

Comment: @MadsKristensen please look into using `MySQLi` as the current form of MySQL you are using is ***Deprecated*** . It's good to learn the differences sooner rather than later!

Comment: @MadsKristensen Hi again :) The reason that your headers do not align to the rows is because you have two tables. Remove `</table><table>` before the loop.

Comment: Hello again :-). Ok I can see that I have to study some more on it, before I understand it. It is pretty much code for a newbie like me :-) I will see if I can find some literature on it. Thanks a lot for the answers

Comment: I just edited my question with a new code. Is it something like that, or is it totally the incorrect way?

Comment: The `$row['id']` you added to the link, should be: p_id instead of id.

Comment: Also the hidden input should be in the form.

Comment: Hey Loko. I think I tried everything now. The hidden input should be in this form?
<td class="resultcolumn4"><?php echo $row{'p_id'};?></td>
            <td class="resultcolumn1"><?php echo $row{'date'};?><br></td>
            <td class="resultcolumn2"><?php echo $row{'day'};?></td>
            <td class="resultcolumn3"><?php echo $row{'fromtime'};?></td>
            <td class="resultcolumn4"><?php echo $row{'totime'};?></td>
            <td><a href='link_to_the_add_or_edit?id='.<?php $row['p_id'] ?></td>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To edit the specific row, you would need a **Primary key** in your mysql table. For example you call it: id. Now you would need to get the id from the table as well: `SELECT id, date, day, fromtime, totime FROM addWorkTime`

Use the `$row['id'];` in the while loop and replace the : `<input type="button" value="Edit">` to: `<a href='link_to_the_add_or_edit?id='.<?php $row['id'] ?>` now your url will look like: link_to_the_add_or_edit?id=1 and you can use: `$_GET['id']` on the link_to_the_add_or_edit page. Now when you're on that page, you make sure you remember that id([SESSIONS](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php)) so you can use it on the submit action when you fill in the values.
Example of session:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['id']=$_GET['id'];
```

on the link_to_the_add_or_edit page. After this you can update the row you want like this(when you submit something):

```
update danskebank SET date=['?'] where id= $_SESSION['id']
```

**EDIT(regarding DarkBee's comment):**

Instead of using sessions here, you can also store the $_GET['id'] in a hidden field like this:

```
$id=$_GET['id'];

echo '<input type="hidden" name="name_of_hidden_input" value='.$id.'>';
//and the rest of the form

if($_GET['submit']){

   //Some mysql injection prevention first

   update danskebank SET date=['?'] where id= $_GET['name_of_hidden_input']
}
```

and in the query use: `$_GET['name_of_hidden_input'];`

Comment: Storing the id in the sessions seem bad practise to me. What if the end-user opens up multiple tabs for fast editing? Then everything will override the last set id in the session

Comment: @DarkBee Kind of far fetched but I do think the OP should learn about Sessions anyhow when working like this. I know people said it's bad practice but I personally never had a situation where it messed up for me. Sessions is just an option and in general it's not bad.

Comment: Thanks a lot of the answers here. I have to study some more on this. It seems to complicated for me :-/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to edit the values of the row try via url:

```
echo '<a href="edit.php?row_id=' . $row_id . '>Edit</a>'; //You should have id for every row
```

Create `edit.php` file and get row's id with `$_GET['row_id']`. Create `form` Add some `input` in it (like this one:`<input type="datetime" />`), and then handle it with another php file. You should execute your  `UPDATE` query there. Like this :

```
$sql = "UPDATE row SET 
            date     = '$date' ,
            day      = '$day' ,
            fromtime = '$fromtime' ,
            totime   = '$totime'
        WHERE id     = $row_id;
";

mysql_query($sql);
```

But for all these you should have `id` for every row in the database.

Comment: thanks a lot of the answer. I will try to see if I can make it.

Comment: @MadsKristensen I want to describe it all with codes, but it will be a very long answer.